# How to get postback element in updatepanel using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, postback

Is there a way to find out postback element in updatepanel using javascript?

I tried code below but args.get_postBackElement().id is undefined.

```
script>
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
     Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

     function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        try {
            args.get_request().set_userContext(args.get_postBackElement().id);
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    }

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        try {
            if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
                var sName = args.get_response().get_webRequest().get_userContext();
                if (sName == "btnDetails") {
                    //DoSomething();
                }
                else {
                    //DoSomethingelse();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

args.get_postBackElement() returns null if control is inside update panel.

Try following properties to find out the element:

**sender._postBackSettings.async** - Detect whether the request is async.

**sender._postBackSettings.asyncTarget** - Gets the async postback control name

**$("*[name='sender._postBackSettings.asyncTarget']").attr('id')** - Gets the id of the async postback control name. sender._postBackSettings.asyncTarget should be replaced by the value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    var postBackElementID;
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        try {
            postBackElementID = args.get_postBackElement().id.substring(args.get_postBackElement().id.lastIndexOf("_") + 1);
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like args.get_postBackElement() always return null if its an async postback. I am able to find out the anwser using _postBackSettings. Thanks for your reply.